# testing an unsecured checkout page

Tags: php, javascript, html, security, ssl-certificate

So I have a new domain set up, with a checkout page for my product. I want to test this page out on live traffic before buying an SSL certificate for this domain. I just want to make a few sales, to make sure that everything is working. My question is:

If I don't have an SSL certificate, will some browsers/antivirus software block users from entering credit card info and/or give them alerts or warnings?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: probably not, you can get a payment gateway where they host the page where the cc number is entered , so you don't even need a ssl

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you accept real credit card numbers without SSL, you will be in direct, major violation of PCI and could be sued by the credit card industry for 6+ figures and lose your merchant account.

A cheap SSL certificate is $8 or so at places like Namecheap. This is not a place you want to risk things.

Comment: depends on "how" he is accepting the cc. All the gateways i work with have an option where they host the page to take the cc details, so the site dies not need to worry about ssl et al

Comment: @Dagon No, it doesn't. Hosting the page without SSL means someone could man-in-the-middle attack and inject JavaScript which sends the form fields off to their servers. This is why solutions like Stripe still tell you to host via SSL.

Comment: the point is you dont have to host the page that you type the cc number into, most payemt gateways will host that page for you - so you dont need an ssl

Comment: Presumably, if the OP is planning on buying an SSL at some point, that's not what's going on here.

Comment: feel free to presume\assume anything you like :-)

Comment: @Snapcaster: if you really are taking CCs yourself rather than forwarding the user to a Payment Service Provider, there are many, many more pieces of PCI-DSS to worry about. You shouldn't be touching a card number from your own code unless you're a big merchant with the not-insignificant resources to look after a PCI-compliant application and hosting environment.

Answer (score 0):

If it's just you testing and you do have a problem then you can disable your antivirus. However, it shouldn't be a problem.

Do not allow regular users to enter credit cards on a non-SSL connection.